# Cannot search nor join on other language other than english

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding

I'm scratching my head on this SQL.
I have already changed data base collation to Chinese_PRC_CI_AS but still cannot join or search on a specific value containing Chinese. This column value comes from Excel file, I'm thinking that there might be something wrong with the excel encoding.

I have tried find the hex string using this:

```
SELECT master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(CAST(Media AS varbinary))   
,Media  
,master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(CAST('汽车之家 Autohome' AS varbinary))
FROM XXX
```

RESULTING different value:

```
0x7d6c668f4b4eb65b0a004100750074006f0068006f006d006500  汽车之家 Autohome   0xc6fbb3b5d6aebcd2204175746f686f6d65
```

The first hex string is the string that I cannot join or search using condition `where`
How can I determine that which encoding that the first string uses?

UPDATE:
Inspired by folks below, using N'', the hex string are the same. But I still could not search string using `where Media = N'汽车之家 Autohome'`. Any ideas why?

UPDATE:
I found out the reason, be aware that the space is not actually the space, but \n or other special character, remove this and all work fine

Comment: Please clarify: 0x7d6c668f4b4eb65b0a004100750074006f0068006f006d006500   is the one you receive from Excel or the result of your cast?
Furthermore: try using CAST(N'汽车之家 Autohome' AS varbinary) instead of CAST('汽车之家 Autohome' AS varbinary)

Comment: @Tyron78, I tried using N'', the results are the same. But I still could not use search or join. Any ideas why?

Comment: Sounds Strange. Could you please try to do a search like `where Media LIKE N'汽车之家%'`?

Comment: @Tyron78 I found out the reason, the space between the chinese and english is actually not the space, but \n, remove this and all work fine

Comment: This is what I wanted to evaluate by the wildcard search with LIKE :-D